# linq to entities - updating tables with new values not working

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, asp.net-webpages

The code below is updating the correct values into the OBJECT_TYPES table, but the OBJECT_ITEMS table is being overwritten but I am not sure why. Can anyone help?

```
 var templateId = Request["id"].AsInt();
var dbcontext = new STDEntities1();
var query = dbcontext.OBJECT_TYPES.Where(o => o.ID == templateId);
var template = query.FirstOrDefault();
var newItem = new OBJECT_TYPES
{
    CATEGORY_ID = template.CATEGORY_ID,
    COMPANY_ID = template.COMPANY_ID,
    OBJECT_NAME = "** Select A Name **",
    HEIGHT = template.HEIGHT,
    WIDTH = template.WIDTH,
    TEMPLATE = template.ID
};


foreach (var field in template.OBJECT_ITEMS)
{
    newItem.OBJECT_ITEMS.Add(field);

}
dbcontext.OBJECT_TYPES.Add(newItem);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: OK - it seems to work if rather than put .Add(field) if I create a new item and add the field values (except for the id, and the foreign key).

Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because you are adding field which actually is an object that is being tracked by the dataContext/dbContext and even has an id. So the values are being overwritten.

Try creating the a new field OR try detaching the field from the context and then put the Id/Primary key to 0 and try inserting it again.

Comment: thanks - that made sense and sort of what I was thinking myself (in a more fuzzy kind of way). Cheers.